# Is there a way to look for a flag in a man page?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, less-unix

I'm trying to come up with a way to find a specific flag in a man-page. Usually, I type '/'
to search for something, followed by something like '-Werror' to find a specific flag.
The thing is though that there are man-pages (gcc is the one motivating me right now) that
have a LOT of references to flags in their text, so there are a lot of occurrences.

It's not that big of a deal, but maybe it can be done a bit better. I thought of looking for
something like '-O\n' but it didn't work (probably because the man program doesn't use C escapes?)
Then I've tried something like `man gcc | grep $'-O\n'`, since I kind of recall that a
single-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign haves bash interpret common C escapes...
It' didn't work, grep echoed the whole man-page.

That's what has brought me here: why? or rather, can this be done?

Comment: An alternative is to use http://explainshell.com, which, given a command with options, explains each option a using information extracted from `man` pages, using a nice GUI; here's the result for `gcc -O`: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=gcc+-O. Note that the `man` pages used are Ubuntu's, and the information therefore applies to _GNU_ utilities.

Comment: I found out about explainshell a while ago, and I am loving it, thanks. Good suggestion.

Comment: So basically, you just use `grep -- -n` or `grep -e -n` to search for `-n` explicitly instead of passing it as a flag to `grep`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[rici's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19199172/45375) explains the problem with the original approach well.

However, there's another thing worth mentioning:

**`man`'s output contains *formatting control characters*, which interfere with text searches**.

If you **pipe to `col -b` before searching**, these control characters are removed - note the side effect that the search results will be plain-text too.

However, **`grep` is not the right tool for this job; I suggest using `awk`** as follows to obtain the description of `-O`:

```
man gcc | col -b | awk -v RS= '/^\s+-O\n/'
```

- `RS=` (an empty input-record separator) is an awk idiom that breaks the input into blocks of non-empty lines, so matching the option at the start of such a block ensures that *all lines comprising the description of the option* are returned.

If you have a POSIX-features-only `awk` such as BSD/OSX `awk`, use this version:

```
man gcc | col -b | awk -v RS= '/^[[:blank:]]+-O\n/'
```

---

Obviously, such a command is somewhat cumbersome to type, so find **generic `bash` function `manopt`** below, which **returns the description of the specified option for the specified command from its `man` page**. (There can be false positives and negatives, but overall it works pretty well.)

Examples:

```
manopt gcc O          # search `man gcc` for description of `-O`
manopt grep regexp    # search `man grep` for description of `--regexp`
manopt find '-exec.*' # search `man find` for all actions _starting with_ '-exec'
```

#### `bash` function `manopt()` - place in `~/.bashrc`, for instance:

```
# SYNOPSIS
#   manopt command opt
#
# DESCRIPTION
#   Returns the portion of COMMAND's man page describing option OPT.
#   Note: Result is plain text - formatting is lost.
#
#   OPT may be a short option (e.g., -F) or long option (e.g., --fixed-strings);
#   specifying the preceding '-' or '--' is OPTIONAL - UNLESS with long option
#   names preceded only by *1* '-', such as the actions for the `find` command.
#
#   Matching is exact by default; to turn on prefix matching for long options,
#   quote the prefix and append '.*', e.g.: `manopt find '-exec.*'` finds
#   both '-exec' and 'execdir'.
#
# EXAMPLES
#   manopt ls l           # same as: manopt ls -l
#   manopt sort reverse   # same as: manopt sort --reverse
#   manopt find -print    # MUST prefix with '-' here.
#   manopt find '-exec.*' # find options *starting* with '-exec'
manopt() {
  local cmd=$1 opt=$2
  [[ $opt == -* ]] || { (( ${#opt} == 1 )) && opt="-$opt" || opt="--$opt"; }
  man "$cmd" | col -b | awk -v opt="$opt" -v RS= '$0 ~ "(^|,)[[:blank:]]+" opt "([[:punct:][:space:]]|$)"'
}
```

---

#### `fish` implementation of `manopt()`:

Contributed by [Ivan Aracki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2884309/ivan-aracki).

```
function manopt 
  set -l cmd $argv[1]
  set -l opt $argv[2] 
  if not echo $opt | grep '^-' >/dev/null
    if [ (string length $opt) = 1 ] 
      set opt "-$opt"
    else
      set opt "--$opt"
    end
  end
  man "$cmd" | col -b | awk -v opt="$opt" -v RS= '$0 ~ "(^|,)[[:blank:]]+" opt "([[:punct:][:space:]]|$)"'
end
```

Comment: @AlexanderWeickmann: Indeed it doesn't, because `jq`'s `man` page is formatted differently than the pages for standard utilities such as `ls`.

Comment: I found I had to edit this a bit. Using your example I had to change it to `MANWIDTH=160 man gcc | col -b | awk -v RS= '/-O,/'`. The previous example, with MANDWITH set, outputs nothing, I'm not sure why. I'd be interested in knowing, but in any case, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you didn't actually use `grep $'-O\n'`, but rather some flag recognized by `grep`.

From grep's point of view, you are simply passing an argument, and that argument starts with a `-` so it's going to be interpreted as an option. You need to do something like `grep -- -O$` to explicitly flag the end of the list of options, or `grep -e -O$` to explicitly flag the pattern as a pattern. In any event, you cannot include a newline in a pattern because grep patterns are actually lists of patterns separated by newline characters, so the argument `$'foo\n'` is actually two patterns, `foo` and the empty string, and the empty string will match every line.

Perhaps you searched for the flag `-e` since that takes a pattern as an argument, and giving it a newline as an argument will cause grep to find every line in the whole file.

For most GNU programs, such as gcc, you might find the `info` interface easier to navigate in, since it includes reference links, tables of contents, and even indices. The `info gcc` document includes an index of options, which is very useful. In some linux distributions, and somewhat surprisingly since they call themselves GNU/linux distributions, it's necessary to separately install `info` packages although `man` files are distributed with the base software. The debian/ubuntu package containing the gcc `info` files is called `gcc-doc`, for example. (The use of the `-doc` suffix to the package name is quite common.)

In the case of `gcc` you can rapidly find an option using a command like:

```
info gcc "option index" O
```

or

```
info gcc --index-search=funroll-loops
```

For programs with fewer options, it's usually good enough to use info's `-O` option:

```
info -O gawk
```

Comment: I just tried `man gcc | grep -- $'-O\n'` and didn't work. But with `grep -- -e '-O$' it does... Although now I feel really stupid, since that evidently returns a line that only contains '-O', which is not usefull at all...

Comment: @ferhtgoldaraz: You probably want to use `-A1` or some such ("`-A NUM` Print  NUM  lines  of  trailing  context after matching lines.")

Comment: @rici: Thanks for the clarifying update. `-e` doesn't actually _necessarily_ take a _regex_ as its argument (despite its long option name, `--regexp`) - it's simply an alternative mechanism for passing _multiple_ patterns as _separate options_ rather than a _single multi-line string_. Thus, for instance, with `-F` (or invoked as `fgrep`) the `-e` arguments are _fixed_ (literal) strings. Another way of putting it: a pattern passed to `-e` is treated the same as one without it (and passing a multi-line string to `-e` also results in multiple patterns).

Comment: @mklement0: yeah, I didn't fix the word `regex` in the unedited text. For the sake of thoroughness I'll change the word.

Comment: @mklement0: ... and add more examples of `info`, which is actually a lot more useful for monstrous docs like gcc and bash.

Comment: Thanks. Looks handy for `gcc` (I actually got errors installing `gcc-doc` on Ubuntu 14.04 and only the `--index-search` option works as expected), but support for these options with utilities such as `awk`, `grep`, `sed`, `find`, ... is spotty and inconsistent, unfortunately. E.g., most act no different when invoked with `-O`, and some make it hard to get to a list of options (e.g., `grep`); `--index-search` works with `sed`, but not `awk`, ...

Comment: I like your approach - jumping to the information of interest in context of the documentation - better than mine (extracting an isolated piece of information), but it looks like there's no unified solution.

Comment: @mklement0: `info` falls back to manpages, so you need to call `gawk` `gawk` if you want `info` about it. (You probably have a man alias.) I agree that some of the info pages are not as well-organized as others, and ubuntu's doc packages are not what one might expect in a developer-oriented distro. But that's not ubuntu's purpose. Anyway, "patches welcome". Oh, and if --index-search doesn't find the right index entry, type a comma.

Comment: Thanks; re `--index-search`: type a comma where?

Comment: @mklement0: after it shows you the wrong index entry. `,` means "show the next similar index entry". By the way, Debian/Ubuntu consider `info`'s own `info` file non-free, so you have to `apt-get install texinfo-doc-nonfree` to get it. Far from obvious.

Comment: Got it, thanks; however, `info <cmd> --index-search=...` doesn't seem to find _anything_ for `gawk` and `find`, for instance. By contrast, works OK for `sed` and `cut`, for instance. As a minor point of interest: OSX is _also_ running _GNU_ `info` (version 4.8 as of OSX 10.9.4).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58061/discussion-between-rici-and-mklement0).

Comment: I think `info --vi-keys` should be mentioned, since it turns on normal (`man`-like) keybindings for `info`

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that 'man' uses a pager, commonly 'less', whose man-page states:

```
/pattern
    Search  forward  in  the file for the N-th line containing the pattern.
    N defaults to 1.  The pattern is a regular expression, as recognized by the
    regular expression library supplied by your system.  The search starts at the
    first line displayed (but see the -a and -j options, which change this).
```

So one could try and look for '-O$' in a man-page to find a flag that lives alone in it's
own line. Although, it is common for a flag to be followed by text in the very same line,
so this is not guaranteed to work.

The issue with grep and $'-O\n' is still a mystery though.

Comment: I don't intend to trick the system or anything by adding an answer to my own question, I actually looked it up first and came up with [this meta stack overflow question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions) addressing the possible issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
man gcc | grep "\-"
```

This works pretty well, as it displays all flags and usually not much more.

Edit: I notice I didn't completely answer your question, but I hope my suggestion can be considered as a nice alternative.

Comment: The backslash in that search pattern is pointless. And with or without the backslash, it returns 5160 of the 12737 lines of `man gcc`. You can cut it down a bit by limiting it to things that look more like options: `man gcc | grep ' -[[:alpha::]]'` returns 3788 lines, for example. Of course, gcc has a *lot* of options, and you rarely really want to look at all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I use folowing:

`man some_command | col -b | grep -A5 -- 'your_request'`

Examples:

- `man man | col -b | grep -A5 -- '-K'`
- `man grep | col -b | grep -A5 -- '-e patt'`

You can make alias for it.

Answer (score 1):

The [manly](https://github.com/carlbordum/manly) Python utility is very convenient for getting a quick explanation of all options used in a given command.

Note that it only outputs the first paragraph of the option descriptions.

```sh
pip install manly
```

```
$ manly blkid /dev/sda -o value -p

blkid - locate/print block device attributes
============================================

      -o, --output format
              Use  the  specified output format.  Note that the order of vari‐
              ables and devices is not fixed.  See also option -s.  The format
              parameter may be:

      -p, --probe
              Switch to  low-level  superblock  probing  mode  (bypassing  the
              cache).
```

Answer (score 1):

> a double dash (--) is used in most bash built-in commands and many other commands to signify the end of command options

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/204245

Without the double-dash, `grep` is trying to use whatever flag you are looking for:

```sh
$ man curl | grep -c # Looks for this c flag, but can't find one so throws the error below.
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

If you use double-dash to signify the end of input to `grep`, it works a bit better, but you still end up with *every* occurrence of the match:

```sh
$ man curl | grep -- -c
       --cacert <file>
              certs file named 'curl-ca-bundle.crt', either in the same direc-
       --capath <dir>
              curl to make SSL-connections much more  efficiently  than  using
              --cacert if the --cacert file contains many CA certificates.
       --cert-status
       --cert-type <type>
       -E, --cert <certificate[:password]>
       --ciphers <list of ciphers>
# ...many more matches......
```

So simply wrap the flag in quotes and throw a space before it to only match the `-c` flag:

```sh
$ man curl | grep -- " -c"
       -c, --cookie-jar <filename>
```

This has driven me insane for years. Hope this helps.

Comment: This tip has fundamentally improved my day-to-day working with the command line.

Answer (score 0):

`man` is based on an environment variable (`EDITOR` if I'm not mistaking). You can change this from `more` (the default value) to, e.g., `emacs`, and then while using `man` an `emacs` session gets opened on your system, where you can search and browse as you like.